# Which Web HTML form component to use

Tags: html

Excuse if this is a simple question, but it has been some time since I got stuck into code and/or web GUI's.

I am trying to build an interface for matching of two sets of data.  What I had in mind was a list of items from data set 1 in a list in the left hand side and a corresponding list of items from data set 2 on the right hand side.  I want the user to be able to choose and item (or items) in the left hand side and then choose the matching item (or items) in the right hand side and then hit a button to match them together (essentially associate those items together).

I can do the association in the back-end.  But the HTML element needs to be able to display items from each of the two lists in seperate areas and then when the button is clicked, pass the ID's of the items that have been selected in the left and right lists to the back-end that will then associate them together in the database.

What elements would you suggest I use for something like this (which I assume is fairly trivial).

Thanks

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, your question is pretty broad and could be opinion based. Give something a shot with probably radiobuttons, checkboxes, or select elements and come on back when you have a more particular issue with code. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need `<input type="checkbox">`. That input is used when you need to play with multiple objects at once. Make sure you give it a `name="whatever_you_want"` attribute too.

If you only wanted to use one selection, you'd use `<input type="radio">`.

You can also use the following with multiple options inside it:

```
<select>
   <option value="your_value1">Displayed value 1</option>
   <option value="your_value2">Displayed value 2</option>
   <!-- and so on.... -->
</select>
```

I don't know why you guys downvoted his question. It was pretty clear when I read it, though maybe he edited it later. I know the question could be broad in some sense, but he said he could do the backend just fine...

Comment: Thanks for your response.  A specific response to what I also thought was a specific question.  I didn't change the question so I am also not sure why it was downvoted.  Oh well...I played around with HTML about 15 years ago so thought things might have changed since then (..HTML5 etc).  But seem like this aspect is still the same.

Comment: Your welcome. But please upvote my answer so people know it's been answered, and you don't get aymore downvotes.

Comment: You gotta vote up the answer so it's accepted, not my comment.